# Define a method that has many (or infinite) arguments

Tags: objective-c, syntax, arguments

The `initWithObjects:` method of `NSArray` takes an indefinite list of arguments:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:(id), ..., nil
```

How can I define my own method like this?

```
- (void)CustomMethod:????? <= want to take infinite arguments {

}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The "infinite arguments" are variable arguments and the methods that use them are called variadic methods. You define them the same way as your `NSMutableArray` example. Apple's [Technical Q&A](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1405/_index.html) has an example of how to implement it.

```
- (void) appendObjects:(id) firstObject, ...
{
    id eachObject;
    va_list argumentList;
    if (firstObject) // The first argument isn't part of the varargs list,
    {                                   // so we'll handle it separately.
        [self addObject: firstObject];
        va_start(argumentList, firstObject); // Start scanning for arguments after firstObject.
        while ((eachObject = va_arg(argumentList, id))) // As many times as we can get an argument of type "id"
            [self addObject: eachObject]; // that isn't nil, add it to self's contents.
        va_end(argumentList);
    }
}
```

The reason for the `nil` argument is so that you know when you have reached the end of the list. Functions like `NSLog` and `printf` do not require the last argument to be `nil` because it can count the number of specifiers in the format string (`%d`, `%s` etc...)

Comment: Should `while (eachObject = va_arg(argumentList, id))` be `while (eachObject == va_arg(argumentList, id))`?

Comment: No it is an assignment not a comparison. I should surround it with an extra pair of parenthesis though.

Comment: The fact that the implementation requires so much syntax garbage kind of defeats the purpose of a var arg method.

Comment: Hmm, but how much overhead do these methods take?